# Calling Method on Child View in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have an `ImageEditView` that contains an `ImageCanvasView` and an `ImageCaptureButton`.

Ideally, I want `ImageCaptureButton` to call a method on `ImageCanvasView` called `takeScreenshot`.

How do I achieve this in SwiftUI? I've been thinking of trying to save `ImageCanvasView` into a variable in `ImageEditView` so that my `ImageCaptureButton` can then call its method, but SwiftUI's declarative nature means this isn't possible.

----- EDIT below -----

The flow is as follows:

1. ImageSelectView (user selects an image)
2. ImageEditView (user edits an image) - this view contains ImageCanvasView and ImageCaptureButton
3. ImageShareView (user shares the image)

The following is ImageEditView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImageEditView: View {
    
    @State var selectedImage: Image
    
    @State private var isNavLinkPresented = false
    @State private var imageSnapshot: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    var canvasView: ImageCanvasView = ImageCanvasView(selectedImage: $selectedImage) 
    // this won't work: Cannot use instance member '$selectedImage' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
        
    var body: some View {

            VStack {
                canvasView
                Spacer()
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ImageShareView(imageToShare: $imageSnapshot), isActive: $isNavLinkPresented) {
                        Text("Next")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                imageSnapshot = canvasView.takeScreenshot()
                                isNavLinkPresented = true
                            }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Edit image"))
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right direction. By creating var of the view, you can call the function.
Here is the example demo

```
struct ImageEditView: View {
    
    var canvasView: ImageCanvasView = ImageCanvasView()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ImageEditView")
            canvasView
            Button("ImageCaptureButton") {
                canvasView.takeScreenshot()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ImageCanvasView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ImageCanvasView")
    }
    
    func takeScreenshot() {
        print(#function + " Tapped ")
    }
}
```

You can also use computed property to pass data

```
struct ImageEditView: View {
    var data: String = ""
    var canvasView: ImageCanvasView {
        ImageCanvasView(data: data)
    }
    
   // Body code
}

struct ImageCanvasView: View {
    var data: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("ImageCanvasView")
    }
    
    func takeScreenshot() {
        print(#function + " Tapped ")
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Use init to use the same instance of ImageCanvasView.

```
struct ImageEditView: View {
    
    @State var selectedImage: Image
    
    @State private var isNavLinkPresented = false
    @State private var imageSnapshot: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    var canvasView: ImageCanvasView!

    init(selectedImage: Image) {
        self.selectedImage = selectedImage
        canvasView = ImageCanvasView(selectedImage: $selectedImage)
    }
    // Other code
```

Comment: Thanks Raja. But what if I need to pass a parameter into ImageCanvasView, and this parameter is itself passed into ImageEditView from an earlier view? Creating ImageCanvasView as a var means I cannot do that.

Comment: Can you please add some code? what is your code flow?

Comment: I think at that time you need computed property

Comment: Added my code in the original post as an edit

Comment: @thecanteen use computed property as I mentioned in last.

```var canvasView: ImageCanvasView {
        ImageCanvasView(selectedImage: $selectedImage)
    }```

Comment: Hey Raja - for computed property, it will create a new instance of ImageCanvasView when I call it. But it is important I call the same instance as the one that was rendered in the view. Any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: Use init of the view.

Comment: @thecanteen updated answere

Comment: The final version will result in SwiftUI complaint: `Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.` from `canvasView = ImageCanvasView(selectedImage: $selectedImage)`

Comment: Creating a var of the view won't work, and also placing it in init is the same as initialising it anywhere else. The view is a struct, so wherever you use it, the value will be copied, not passed by reference. When you pass it in to SwiftUI, it gets copied.